# Java add all table data into list

Tags: java, servlets

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|  Name  |number |qty  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|   ab   |   5   |  7  |
+--------+-------+-----+ 
|   cd   |   1   |  6  |
+--------+-------+-----+ 
|   ef   |   0   |  9  |
+--------+-------+-----+ 
|   gh   |   8   |  2  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I'm showing this example product table. I need to get this all table date into one jsp without using resultset. I tried to do up to this part:

```
public Product search(){
    Product p = null;
    ResultSet rs = DAO.fetch("SELECT * FROM Products");
    if (rs.next()) {
        p = new Product();
        p.setNumber(rs.getString("ProductNumber"));
        p.setName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        p.setQty(rs.getString("ProductQty"));

    }
    return p;
}
```

I need to add all table data in to list or ?? and return it using method how do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `search()` method return a `List<Product>` instead of a single `Product`.

```
public List<Product> search(){
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    ResultSet rs = DAO.fetch("SELECT * FROM Products");
    while (rs.next()) {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setNumber(rs.getString("ProductNumber"));
        product.setName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        product.setQty(rs.getString("ProductQty"));
        products.add(product);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Then, in your JSP file, iterate over the returned list:

```jsp
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
    <!-- build your row -->
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: How do i get product name,qty,number using that List<Product>

Comment: can u please tell me how is getting data is works? if i want to get |   cd   |   1   |  6  | how do i take it?

Comment: Also to to see it in JSP you have to add products (product list) to request as a attribute. request.setAttribute("products",products)

Comment: and if i need to get all the names?

Comment: check the documentation of the MVC framework you are using, in order to know how to pass variables between layers.

Comment: make sure to add <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> in your jsp