# How to display table contents on a jsp page from Derby DB?

Tags: java, jsp, derby

I have 2 pages a userAdmin and a productAdmin and when I click into them the page loads but it doesn't display any of the relevant data from the Derby DB. For the sake of the example I'm going to show the user data. [Image of the page - table is not being populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4DU2.png) The layout of the table isn't great but it's basic code given to us by a lecturer for an assignment. Once I fix this out, I'll make it look better. It should also have links to edit and delete users but it is currently only displaying add
So here is all the relevant code/info

The user logins in as an admin and goes to the admin page and clicks "userAdmin" - this goes to the userAdminServlet

```
public class userAdminServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    UserManager uServ = new UserManager();
    
    String url = null;
    String query = null; 
    
    if (action == null)
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    
    // Code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108960/java-add-all-table-data-into-list
    if (action.equals("listUsers")){
        ArrayList<User> users = uServ.getAllUsers();
        request.setAttribute("users", users);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
        
    }
        
    
    
    if (action.equals("add")){
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/addUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    if (action.equals("delete")){
        deleteUser(request,response);
        ArrayList<User> users = uServ.getAllUsers();
        request.setAttribute("users", users);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    if (action.equals("insertUser")){
        insertUser(request,response);
        ArrayList<User> users = uServ.getAllUsers();
        request.setAttribute("users", users);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    if (action.equals("updateCompleteUser")){
        updateUser(request,response);
        ArrayList<User> users = uServ.getAllUsers();
        request.setAttribute("users", users);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    if (action.equals("edit")){
        String userId = request.getParameter("id");
        
        if (userId == null)
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        else {
            long uId = 0;
            uServ = new UserManager();
            User oldUser = uServ.getUser(uId);
            request.setAttribute("oldUser", oldUser);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/editUser.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
           
    }
    else
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/userAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);
  
   
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request,response);
   
}

private void insertUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String userType = request.getParameter("userType");
    
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.setPassword(password);
    newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
    newUser.setLastName(lastName);
    newUser.setUserType(userType);
    
    UserManager uServ = new UserManager();
    uServ.insertUser(newUser);
    
    
    
}

private void updateUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    
    long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String userType = request.getParameter("userType");
    
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setId(id);
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.setPassword(password);
    newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
    newUser.setLastName(lastName);
    newUser.setUserType(userType);
    
    UserManager uServ = new UserManager();
    uServ.updateUser(newUser);
    
    
    
}

private void deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    
    long userId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    UserManager uServ = new UserManager();
    uServ.deleteUser(userId);
    return;

}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

This is the UserDAO code:

```
public class UserDAO {

public User getUserByEmail(String email) {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();
    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();
    long userID = 0;
    String password = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String userType = null;
    User tempUser = new User();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM USERDATA WHERE EMAIL=" + "'" + email + "'";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            userID = (rs.getLong(1));
            password = (rs.getString(3));
            firstName = (rs.getString(4));
            lastName = (rs.getString(5));
            userType = (rs.getString(6));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tempUser.setEmail(email);
    tempUser.setId(userID);
    tempUser.setFirstName(firstName);
    tempUser.setLastName(lastName);
    tempUser.setPassword(password);
    tempUser.setUserType(userType);
    return tempUser;

}

public User getUserById(long userId) {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();
    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();
    String email = null;
    String password = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String userType = null;
    User tempUser = new User();

    String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM USERDATA WHERE USER_ID=%d", userId);
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            email = (rs.getString(2));
            password = (rs.getString(3));
            firstName = (rs.getString(4));
            lastName = (rs.getString(5));
            userType = (rs.getString(6));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tempUser.setId(userId);
    tempUser.setEmail(email);
    tempUser.setPassword(password);
    tempUser.setFirstName(firstName);
    tempUser.setLastName(lastName);
    tempUser.setUserType(userType);
    return tempUser;

}

public ArrayList<User> getAllUsers() {

    DBManager dm = new DBManager();
    Connection con = dm.getConnection();

    int userID = 0;
    String email = null;
    String password = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String userType = null;
    User tempUser = new User();

    ArrayList<User> userData = new ArrayList();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM USERDATA";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            userID = (rs.getInt(1));
            email = (rs.getString(2));
            password = (rs.getString(3));
            firstName = (rs.getString(4));
            lastName = (rs.getString(5));
            userType = (rs.getString(6));

            tempUser.setId(userID);
            tempUser.setEmail(email);
            tempUser.setFirstName(firstName);
            tempUser.setLastName(lastName);
            tempUser.setPassword(password);
            tempUser.setUserType(userType);
            userData.add(tempUser);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userData;

}

public void insertUser(User newUser) {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();
    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO USERDATA(EMAIL,PASSWORD,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,USERTYPE) "
                + "VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", newUser.getEmail(), newUser.getPassword(), newUser.getFirstName(), newUser.getLastName(), newUser.getUserType());
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public void updateUser(User newUser) {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();
    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = String.format("UPDATE USERDATA SET email='%s',password='%s',fname='%s',lname='%s',usertype='%s' where user_id=%d ", newUser.getEmail(), newUser.getPassword(), newUser.getFirstName(), newUser.getLastName(), newUser.getUserType(), newUser.getId());
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void deleteUser(long userId) {

    DBManager dmbgr = new DBManager();
    Connection con = dmbgr.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM USERDATA WHERE USER_ID=%d", userId);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is the UserManager code:

```
public class UserManager {

/**
 * This will take a username and select from user table This will return
 * three possible statuses, login correct, unknown user or password
 * incorrect
 *
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @return
 */
public User loginUser(String email, String password) {

    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    User user = userDAO.getUserByEmail(email);
    if (user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return user;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public User getUser(long userId) {
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    User user = userDAO.getUserById(userId);
    return user;
}

public ArrayList<User> getAllUsers() {

    UserDAO uDao = new UserDAO();
    ArrayList<User> userList = uDao.getAllUsers();
    return userList;

}

public void insertUser(User nUser) {
    UserDAO uDao = new UserDAO();
    uDao.insertUser(nUser);
    

}

public void updateUser(User nUser) {
    UserDAO uDao = new UserDAO();
    uDao.updateUser(nUser);
 

}

public void deleteUser(long userId) {
    UserDAO uDao = new UserDAO();
    uDao.deleteUser(userId);
    

}
```

}

And finally this is the userAdmin.jsp file where everything is being outputted - I'll just post the relevant code, I have the jstl import included anyway but all the code from this page won't format properly to post!

```
    <div class="container bg-light">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="my-4">User Administration</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                                                 
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach items="${User}" var="user">
                                <c:url value="/userAdminServlet" var="editUserUrl">
                                    <c:param name="action" value="edit"/>
                                    <c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/>
                                </c:url>
                                <c:url value="/userAdminServlet" var="deleteUserUrl">
                                    <c:param name="action" value="delete"/>
                                    <c:param name="id" value="${user.id}"/>
                                </c:url>
                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="row">${user.id}</td>
                                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                                    <td>${user.firstName}</td>
                                    <td>${user.lastName}</td>
                                    <td><a href="${editUserUrl}"> Edit</a><a href="${deleteUserUrl}">Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <c:url value="/userAdminServlet" var="addUserUrl">
                                    <c:param name="action" value="add"/>
                                </c:url>
                                <td><a href="${addUserUrl}"> Add </a></td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>      

                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <br/>
    </div>
```

There's a really good chance that it's just a small typo or something because in a sample project he's given us, everything ran fine and displayed on the page, I've been looking at this for days so I would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes to see where I'm going wrong, any help at all would be most appreciated!

Comment: Hi, this `${User}` should be `${users}` because you have set that value i.e : request.setAttribute("users", users); change that and see if that works

Comment: @Swati thank you so much, that worked but I'm having a slight issue with it as it displays the same user for every entry in the database? So  I have 3 (three) entries in the db and it displays the last entry for all 3 entries, they all have the ID of 3 with the same details? And when you delete the ID 3 (three) entry it displays 2 entries, both with the ID 2 and the relevant details

Comment: see what `uServ.getAllUsers()` is giving you back .Also , you need specify which value to delete when you click on `a` tag  so attach id as well inside your url.

Comment: @Swati I'm not sure what you mean by what uServ.getAllUsers() is giving you back? I ran the debugger and it just says that the breakpoint hit at line whatever it was on. And where does the id go in the <a> I tried "${deleteUserUrl.user.id}" but that threw an error?